# LINQ and performance with typed and untyped datasets?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dataset, linq-to-dataset

Has anybody had a chance to compare and measure performance of LINQ with typed and untyped datasets?

What are the internal implementation differences of these two. I know that LINQ-to-SQL uses expression trees to generate SQL from LINQ? Is there something similar with LINQ with untyped datasets?

I know that this might seem like a already asked question, but what I'm trying to find out is are there numbers that say for example use untyped datasets with LINQ instead of strongly typed ones or vice versa.

Comment: I don't have exact numbers, but don't expect optimal performance with working with LINQ and DataSets.

Is there a reason why you are using DataSets typed or un-typed over building out our objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any significant differences. Typed datasets are just codegenerated typed wrappers over traditional datasets. Also Linq doesn't generate SQL when querying datasets, because datasets are just objects in memory.